# Две проблемы: (1) прокрутка фона Popup и (2) выползание сайта за экран

Tags: javascript, ios, popup

1) Когда открываю на мобильнике (вертикально или горизонтально) – Popup на своём сайте, то фон под ним (то есть сам сайт = body = #Block) прокручивается вместе с модальным окном (попапом).

Нужно зафиксировать фон во время открытого модального окна.

Подсказали это решение (скорее всего верное), но не пойму как его применить:
https://stanko.github.io/ios-safari-scoll-position-fixed/

2) Вторая ситуация тоже с мобильника, но в вертикальном режиме страница уходит чутка вправо, за экран. Нужно чтобы не выходило за край))

Вот код Popup:

```
  .b-popup {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    }

    .b-popup .b-popup-content {
    margin: 3%;
    width: 80%;
    height: auto; 
    padding: 35px 42px 33px 45px;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 70px 10px #4b4b4b;
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
    }
```

Код сайта – длинный, поэтому сюда копировать не буду.
Вот ссылка на исходник:
view-source:https://yurii-hets.blogspot.com/

Вот сам сайт:
https://yurii-hets.blogspot.com/#prices

p.s. дело имеем с iOS.

p.p.s. попап это зелёные кнопки в прайсе.

Answer (score 0):

Второй вопрос решён!

Всё дело было в – «meta viewport».
Нужно было вообще убрать «initial-scale»:

**Было:**

<s>`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width", initial-scale="1">`</s>

**Стало:**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```